# Persistence.xml editor

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, persistence, dali

I use eclipse kepler (java EE) and when I open editor I can't see the tabs like here:
https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/task_manage_persistence.htm
All I get is persistence.xml tab.

Comment: You mean the tabs at the bottom?

Comment: Do you actually have the Eclipse Dali plug-ins installed (part of the Web Tools)?

Comment: Yes, the tabs at the bottom, it's installed from here http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, it happens when you have android plugins installed. It opens android xml editor instead of the persistence one.
Right click on it -> Open with -> Persistence XML Editor!